# You don't have the permission to access the requested resource error is geven when a post request is sent

Tags: python, flask

I am tring to send a 'POST' request and catch it from python backend. I use flask python framework. Actually, I am doing changes to already developed application.

in the templates I found the code that generate the relavent html.

```
<div class="body">
                    <p>
                        Upload files for the customer {{customer.CustomerName}}.
                    </p>
                    <p>

                    </p>

                    <form method="POST"  action="/admin/customers/{{ customer.ID }}/file_uploading/">

                        <!--   <input type="file" name="pdfFiles"> -->

                            <br><br>
                     <!--     <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit"> -->
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-transparent">Upload</button>
                    </form>



</div>
```

Here, I try to catch the POST request.

```
@app.route('/admin/customers/<cust_id>/<action>/', methods=[ 'GET', 'POST' ])
@login_required
def main_admin_customers(cust_id=None, action=None, subaction=None):
 if cust_id == None:
        c = customers.customer_details()
        return render_template('admin_customers_list.html', 
            customers=c.list_customers())
    else:
        if cust_id.isdigit():
            cust_id = int(cust_id)
            c = customers.customer_details(customerid=cust_id)
            cust_data = c.retrieve_customer()
            if cust_data == None:
                return error_message(message='No such customer.')
            else:
                user = request.cookies['username']


                if action == None:
                    s = scheduling.schedule(customer_id=cust_id)
                    return render_template('admin_customers_view.html')               

                # file uploading 
                # if the action is file_upload and required file is there
                # upload it to the file server. 
                # file url and relevent information should be store in the database
                # files will be categorise for each customer from their ID.

                elif action == 'file_uploading':
                    return redirect(url_for('main_admin_customers', 
                        cust_id=cust_id))





                 # Simple asset creation 
                elif action == 'create_asset':
                    pass
```

However, I get the following error

```
Forbidden

You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
```

However, when I debug the code, as soon as I submit the form, I get the above error message. It didn't even hit the break points at `main_admin_customers`.

What is the mistake I've done here?

Comment: Well... you've got the whole function wrapped in a `login_required` decorator. Not to start with the obvious, but are you certain you have a valid session?

Comment: yes, I in order to view the above html,first I need to do the login. what do you mean by "Not to start with the obvious"? Is that a wrong idea to use the login_required decorator?

Comment: No, I just mean that I didn't want to cause offense by stating the obvious. You're requiring a valid login and receiving an error that suggests you don't have a valid login. CSRF was my next guess, looks like you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following page explain the reason. Basically, I need to include csrf token.
https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf.html

```
If the template has a form, you don’t need to do any thing. It is the same as before:

<form method="post" action="/">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
</form>

But if the template has no forms, you still need a csrf token:

<form method="post" action="/">
    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
</form>
```